# curly braces in subscript causing rendering issues in mathjax

Tags: mathjax

The snippet `$ a_b c_d $` renders properly, but `$ a_b c_{d} $` does not. Does anybody have any idea of what might be the cause or how to fix it? I have some cases where I do need to use curly braces for subscripts like `c_{t + 1}`

edit: I should also mention that I'm using mathjax in conjunction with remarkjs for a presentation. Maybe there is some notation clash with the markdown parser.

Comment: There is a notation clash with the Markdown browser.  Try using `$ a\_b c\_{d} $`.  The issue is that Markdown uses underscores to indicate italics.  My recollection is that they have to be at the beginning and ending of words, and the `{` would be a word break, so that would make the `_` be at the end of a word.  Not sure why `a_b` would count, though.

Comment: great, that fixed it!